# Howto add a batch file to CodeGear C++ Builder ProjectGroup file

Tags: ide, c++builder

I'm looking for a way to add and execute a .bat file in a CodeGear C++ Builder XE3 IDE project group file. More specifically, the batch file should be executed before a certain project is built.

The batch file is just moving a few files around.

Does anyone know how to do that?

My group file have many projects, and some need certain files to be present in a particular folder, hence the .bat file.

Comment: What do you mean *add a batch file* specifically? You can add it to the project group by using the Project Manager, but that just means it's considered part of the project. It doesn't make it do anything. You'll need to be more clear what your intent is before we can answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To be clearer, I need a way, not using the pre/post build features of a project, to execute a batch file, before compiling linking a subsequent project. Perhaps one can create some kind of 'empty' project and execute the batch file in that projects postbuild section. But that seem awkward.

Comment: The way to execute it *is* a pre/post build event. Why can't you use them, since that's *exactly* what they're designed for?

Comment: I am aware of, and are frequently using the pre/post build events. Thats all great. This particular batch file do not semantically belong to a specific project, and therefore need _not_ be part of a project.

Comment: You really should [edit] your question and make it more clear what you're asking, and explain what you're trying to do rather than do so in the comments. Details that are relevant should be in the question itself where they can be seen, instead of buried in the clutter of comments. I'm still not clear why build events wouldn't work; the event can be used for all of the projects, which you seem to indicate is necessary in your last paragraph (and comments).

Comment: I agree about clutter, and did update the question.

Comment: I'm afraid your edit didn't help much. It doesn't explain anything about why you don't think you can use build events - in fact, it clearly says that you need it to execute *before a certain project is built*, which is precisely what a pre-build event is designed to accomplish. If the files need to be there before the specific project is built, it seems to *semantically belong to a specific project*. It's more unclear to me now than it was when I posted my first comment.

Comment: I have the exact same needs as you, copying some files into the project folder before a project is build, and I do this with the Pre Build event. What's the problem with it? The bat file does't have to be on the project folder nor the project itself for it to work (although is easier that way, as you don't have to hard-link it), but it works perfectly fine. As far as I can see, you don't need anything special to solve your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Codegear doesn't offer such options if you want to create empty templates and add them to the project you should do that manually before building your project by `executing your bat file` or `copying your template (DFM,CPP & H) Files to your project structure` and `add them to your project manually` (import using the + button) before executing the build.